# How to pass generated HTML to the render function in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Is it a legit way to pass generated HTML in the render function of the component in JSX?

```
...
//get variables elsewhere
const input = <input type={inputType} ... /> 

return (
  {input}
)
...
```

When I've tried to build it as a string, e.g. `const input = '<input type="' + inputType'" + />'` it was rendered as a plain text.

---

Actually, my `return` is:

```
return (
    <div>{input}</div>
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've posted is perfectly fine other than the `return` (we'll get to that in a moment); you don't need or want to use a string instead.

Remember that JSX is just syntactic sugar for JavaScript code:

```
const input = <input type={inputType} />;
```

...is just a sugared version of [`React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement):

```
const input = React.createElement("input", { type: inputType });
```

It creates the element object, which you can certainly pass around between functions, and which you can render by returning it from `render`.

To do that return, you want simply:

```
return input;
```

Your `return ({input})` won't work because you're trying to use the JSX syntax for inserting a JavaScript expression (`{...}`) *outside* JSX.

Live Example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  getTheThing() {
    const inputType = "text";
    const input = <input type={inputType} />;
    return input;
  }
  render() {
    const input = this.getTheThing();
    return input;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

---

Re your edit:

> Actually, my return is:
>
> ```
> return (
>     <div>{input}</div>
> )
> ```

That's fine (other than the missing `;` — I don't care for relying on ASI), because you're using `{...}` in a JSX block (`<div>...</div>`).

Live Example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  getTheThing() {
    const inputType = "text";
    const input = <input type={inputType} />;
    return input;
  }
  render() {
    const input = this.getTheThing();
    return (
        <div>{input}</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually input is wrapped in a div – I'll edit the example code. Will that be correct?

Comment: @Runnick: Yes, that's fine; I've updated the answer. When adding something like that to a question, if the previous version has already been addressed in an answer, don't edit the question so that it invalidates the answer. I've edited the question to fix that. :-)